# Input keypress problem with spacebar and tab

Tags: javascript, html, css, input

So I have a few forms at my App and they all seem to be working just fine except from one.

When I press spacebar or tab it's like I have a prevent default and it wont do anything.

I've tried using console's code `getEventListeners(node)` and it comes back clean. I also tried using a eventListener to see if the input gets something

```js
let input = document.querySelector('#input')
input.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
  console.log(e.which);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" id="input" name="label" placeholder="Label" class="d-block w-100 mb-3 watch">
  <textarea name="comentario" placeholder="Deixe um comentário" class="d-block w-100 mb-3 watch"></textarea>
  <button class="btn btn-primary">Ok</button>
</form>
```

When I press spacebar or tab console prints the keycode just fine but they don't do the expected.

This app is kinda of a large project and there might be some code bugging my input but I've checked every possibility that I could think of so if anyone has any suggestions they would be welcome.

I'm using JavaScript, HTML and CSS only.
Libraries: jQuery, SVG.js, Pizzicato.js, Tuna.js, Wavesurfer.js

Comment: so you dont want to do any thing on press of spacebar or tab ?

Comment: No, I want them to work the way that they should, they're normal text inputs

Comment: there isn't an element with id as `input`. there's an input element so should change `#input` to `input` in order to watch from input keydown events. besides that, you code should work normally event for whitespaces

Comment: This does not appear to be reproducible with the minimal code snippets you have shown: https://jsfiddle.net/yjz073wv/

Comment: Seems like you're code should work, You mentioned it's a large project and might be some code bugs.. try to add `input.removeEventListener('keydown')` before binding the keydown event

Comment: guijob it was just an example.
@misorude any ideas why this would happen though?

Comment: @benjah removeEvent is a 2 arg function, I would need to know what function was causing this.

Comment: @LeonardoBezerra I hope this helps https://jsfiddle.net/zLbf5sra/ didn't post as answer because I'm not sure I understood completely :x I just forgot to test your keycodes, but you should be fine with adding an `if(e.keyCode == something)`

Comment: @AndréSilva your fiddle messes up massively, as soon as for example cursor keys get pressed. `value +=` can hardly ever be a correct solution for something like this, because it doesn’t take text cursor position into account at all.

Comment: You can use jquery `unbind()` than

Comment: @AndréSilva it worked you should answer this

Comment: @misorude yea, didn't test much anything, just tried to give him a light for his solution, can't do his job without getting his pay lmao, but this might help a bit more. https://jsfiddle.net/h3o9x5nw/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, I didn't put much effort in the tests but this solution could show you the path to be a rockstar with what you need.

https://jsfiddle.net/h3o9x5nw/1/

You can add the codes to test in the `codes` array so the behavior can continue without breaking the user experience. And if you need to test possible keyCodes without losing your mind trying to find something with online tables, you can use https://keycode.info/ to find your keyCodes in JS.

```
document.querySelector('#comentarios').addEventListener('keydown', e => {
            if (e.which == 32){
                e.preventDefault();
                e.path[0].value += String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
            }
        })
```

or

```
document.querySelector('#comentarios').addEventListener('keydown', e => {
            if (e.which != 32) return;

            e.preventDefault();
            e.path[0].value += String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);

        })
```

Comment: `e.which` and `e.keyCode` are both deprecated. `e.key` or `e.code` should be used instead, which also make the code easier to understand. Just keep in mind some old browsers used some non-standard codes, so left is usually `'LeftArrow'` and right is `'RightArrow'`, but on IE and Legacy Edge they would be `'Left'` and `'Right'` instead. Also, take a look at https://keyjs.dev. I will add information about these kinds of cross-browser incompatibilities soon! 

Answer (score 0):

You targeted an id with the name of #input,which can do for example some colors and not actual input.Remove the # and you should target correctly all the other inputs.

Comment: The javascript snippet was just an exemple of what I've tried. And i tell you that console prints just fine.

Comment: `querySelector` uses CSS selectors, and `#input` selects the element with the id `input`. Nothing wrong regarding that, your “answer” here is completely beyond the point.